# Expansiveness of automorphism of n-torus

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $A$ be an automorphism of the $n$-torus, and $[A]$ the corresponding matrix. Then $A$ is expansive iff the linear map induced by $[A]\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ of $\;\mathbb{R^n}\;$ is expansive.

( A homeomorphism $T:X\to X$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be expansive if $\;\exists\delta>0$ such that if $x\neq y$ then $\;\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $d(T^n(x),T^n(y))>\delta$ )

The forward implication is clear. I am stuck on the reverse implication.

This is one of the step required to prove the result that $A$ is expansive iff $[A]$ has no eigenvalues of modules $1$ as outlined in P.Walters text. Any hints or other references to proofs of the latter result would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't define the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n/\Lambda$ (where $\Lambda$ is a lattice, for example $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}^n$). An obvious choice is $d(x+\Lambda,y+\Lambda) = \inf_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \|x-y-\lambda\|$ where $\|.\|$ is some norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore $d(x+\Lambda,y+\Lambda)  = \|x-y\|$ for $\|x-y\|$ small enough

Comment: @reuns Any metric inducing the topology ( the product topology ).

Comment: Do you see why it solves your problem ?

Comment: @reuns: sorry but no...can you explain a bit ?

Comment: @reuns: $\|T^n(x)-T^n(y)\|$ may not be 'small enough' right ?

Comment: $T^n$ is linear, if $x-y$ is small then $T^n(x-y)$ is small

Comment: @reuns: yeah but this also depends on $n$, on the other hand for each pair $(x,y)$ the corresponding $n$ s.t. $d(T^n(x),T^n(y))>\delta$ may be different and and keep getting large

Comment: The problem is when $x-y$ is small, in that case looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n/\Lambda$  is **the same**. That's **exactly** the statement in your question !

Comment: @reuns: The problem is we are looking at $x-y$ and its iterates with $T^n$ simultaneously. We have to show something like $[A]^k(x-y)$ grows 'nicely'.  Its not about just the transition of $x-y$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: ... The problem is to start with $\|x-y\|$ small and check if $\|A^k(x-y)\|$ stays small for every $k$. Thus looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ doesn't change anything.

Comment: @reuns:And that does not stay small as $k$ increases right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It easy to see that the map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by $[A]$ is expansive iff for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ the set $\{\|[A]^nx\|:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is unbounded. Also note that, in our case, it is enough to find a constant satisfying the expansiveness condition only for pairs $(x,0)$.   Let $c=max\left\{\|A\|,\|A^{-1}\|\right\}$ and $\delta=min\left\{\frac{1}{2c},\frac{1}{4}\right\}$. I claim that $\delta$ is a expansive constant for $A$. To see this, let $x\in [0,1]^n$. If $\|x\|>\delta$, then $$d\left(A^0(x),A^0(0)\right)=\|x\|>\delta$$ So suppose $\|x\|\leq\delta$. Let $k=\inf\left\{|n|:\|[A]^nx\|>\delta\right\}$(its non empty since we are assuming the orbits are unbounded). Then (atleast) one of $$\|[A]^kx\|>\delta$$ $$\|[A]^{-k}x\|>\delta $$ holds. Suppose the first one holds. Then $$\delta<\|[A]^kx\|=\|[A]([A]^{k-1}x)\|\leq c\|[A]^{k-1}x\|\leq c\delta\leq \frac{1}{2} $$ which shows that $[A]^kx\in[-1,1]^n$ and hence $$ d\left(A^k(x),A^k(0)\right)=\|[A]^kx\|>\delta. $$ Similar for the case $\|[A]^{-k}x\|>\delta $. Since $x\in[0,1]^n$ was arbitrary, we are done.